# Woocommerce: finding where a filter is being called from

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I spent days to add this filter on my `Woocommerce` site using `functions.php`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_price_trim_zeros','__return_true');
```

to remove trailing zeros on prices. Then it never worked.

Today I tried a plugin called "Show Action & Filter Hook" and found that this filter was duplicated on my website with another filter having "return_false" value. So when I added priority of 11 to `woocommerce_price_trim_zeros` return_true then it worked.

I have no idea how another filter having return false value was there in the first place and I don't know how I can find which file is calling that filter.

Is there a way to find it?

Comment: You can't just add a filter. The filter calls the function. Check out this link, it should put in in perspective for you. https://pippinsplugins.com/a-quick-introduction-to-using-filters/

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared. It helped me understand about filters better!

Comment: You're welcome. I know it can be daunting at first.

Answer (score 0):

This function retrieve the name of the current action: current_filter()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_action/